# C++ convert from derived class to base class with different template number

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm trying to assign a Derived class to a Base class using pointers, the problem is that the two classes have a different number of template:

```
Base
pcl::Feature< PointInT, PointOutT >
Derived
pcl::FeatureFromNormals< PointInT, PointNT, PointOutT >
```

as you can see from the [inheritance diagram](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_feature_from_normals.html) the two classes are father and child.

But when i try to assign the Derived class to a pointer of the Base class i only obtain this error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘pcl::FeatureFromNormals<pcl::PointXYZRGBA, pcl::Normal, pcl::FPFHSignature33>*’ to ‘pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGBA, pcl::Normal>*’ in initialization
```

Is it possible to assign a Derived class to Base class with different number of Template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with different number (and the order) of template parameters, you're just using the wrong base class type.

As the document said,

```
pcl::FeatureFromNormals< PointInT, PointNT, PointOutT >
```

public derived from

```
pcl::Feature< PointInT, PointOutT >
```

for your case,

```
pcl::FeatureFromNormals<pcl::PointXYZRGBA, pcl::Normal, pcl::FPFHSignature33>
```

's base class should be

```
pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGBA, pcl::FPFHSignature33>
```

not

```
pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGBA, pcl::Normal>
```

Comment: you are right, i'm not very used to c++ syntax and i though you couldn't mix the order of templates in a derived class

Comment: @Luca That (i.e. the order and number of template parameters) doesn't matter at all. It only depends on how the inheritance relationship being declared.